# Laravel 5.4 how do I use Simple Html Dom with it

Tags: laravel-5.4, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net with Laravel 5.4. I put the file in my Classes directory ( App/Classes ) and on the top of my scraper controller I put use App\Classes. When I try to run the function scrape() I get the error

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\file_get_html()
```

The function it is referring to is a helper function that is located outside the class. This should be simple, I just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone comes across this with the same issue I found this https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser and it worked great.